# Symfony 2.2 & Monolog stream handler - auto create directory

Tags: symfony, monolog

I use Symfony 2.2 and Monolog package.

My handlers in Monolog:

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        type: stream
        path: "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%/my-path/error.log"
        level: error
```

But stream handler not auto create directory, if directory not exists.
How to auto create directory? Can event dispatcher, but i not see events on monolog ((

Thank.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution this problem:

- Create own stream handler
- Override base stream handler

Example:

Stream handler:

```
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Component\Monolog;

use Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler as BaseStreamHandler;

class StreamHandler extends BaseStreamHandler
{
    /**
     * @{inerhitDoc}
     */
    public function write(array $record)
    {
        if (null === $this->stream) {
            // From original monolog stream handler
            if (!$this->url) {
                throw new \LogicException('Missing stream url, the stream can not be opened. This may be caused by a premature call to close().');
            }

            $dir = dirname($this->url);

            if (!is_dir($dir)) {
                if(!@mkdir($dir, 0777, TRUE)) {
                    // Control errors
                }
            }
        }

        parent::write($record);
    }
}
```

And override base stream handler in symfony monolog package:

```
<parameter key="monolog.handler.stream.class">Acme\DemoBundle\Component\Monolog\StreamHandler</parameter>
```

**Attention:**
This is a base example override monolog handlers in Symfony 2 package!

Comment: I had to do something similar for `monolog.handler.rotating_file.class` overriding it in parameters and doing the folder creation logic after `RotatingFileHandler`'s constructor, thanks!